# LINQ select one field from list of DTO objects to array

Tags: c#, linq

I have DTO class that defines order line like this:

```
public class Line
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Qty    { get; set; }
}
```

A list of type `Line` is populated like so:

```
List<Line> myLines = new List<Line>();
myLines.Add(new Line() { Sku = "ABCD1", Qty = 1 });
myLines.Add(new Line() { Sku = "ABCD2", Qty = 1 });
myLines.Add(new Line() { Sku = "ABCD3", Qty = 1 });
```

What I want is to use LINQ to get an array of SKUs from the `myLines` List. How can I go about doing that?

I am currently doing it manually like this ...

```
// Get SKU List
List<string> mySKUs = new List<string>();
foreach (Line myLine in myLines)
    mySKUs.Add(myLine.Sku);
string[] mySKUsArray = mySKUs.ToArray();
```

I was trying to google for a solution, but I wasn't sure how to word the question...

P.S. is there any benefit/performance gain in using `LINQ` method to achieve what I am currently doing with `foreach`?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use:

```
var mySKUs = myLines.Select(l => l.Sku).ToList();
```

The `Select` method, in this case, performs a mapping from `IEnumerable<Line>` to `IEnumerable<string>` (the SKU), then `ToList()` converts it to a `List<string>`.

Note that this requires `using System.Linq;` to be at the top of your .cs file.

Comment: `.Select()` is something I was looking into before, however I could not get it working. Check this out, it's not showing me that: http://i.imgur.com/1OSJQdO.png (I only see `Sort`) ...

Comment: @LatheesanKanes Make sure that you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the .cs file...

Comment: Ah ha! I was inside a class, I forgot to add that. Brilliant! thanks.

Comment: @paqogomez Will be similar, though foreach is probably slightly faster - in most cases, the performance for this type of operation *does not matter*.

Answer (score 6):

This is very simple in LinQ... You can use the select statement to get an Enumerable of properties of the objects.

```
var mySkus = myLines.Select(x => x.Sku);
```

Or if you want it as an Array just do...

```
var mySkus = myLines.Select(x => x.Sku).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for;

```
  string[] skus = myLines.Select(x => x.Sku).ToArray();
```

However, if you're going to iterate over the sku's in subsequent code I recommend not using the `ToArray()` bit as it forces the queries execution prematurely and makes the applications performance worse. Instead you can just do;

```
  var skus = myLines.Select(x => x.Sku); // produce IEnumerable<string>

  foreach (string sku in skus) // forces execution of the query
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select all Sku elements of your myLines list and then convert the result to an array.

```
string[] mySKUsArray = myLines.Select(x=>x.Sku).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case you're interested in extremely minor, almost immeasurable performance increases, add a constructor to your `Line` class, giving you such:

```
public class Line
{
    public Line(string sku, int qty)
    {
        this.Sku = sku;
        this.Qty = qty;
    }

    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Qty    { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a specialized collection class based on `List<Line>` with one new method, `Add`:

```
public class LineList : List<Line>
{
    public void Add(string sku, int qty)
    {
        this.Add(new Line(sku, qty));
    }
}
```

Then the code which populates your list gets a bit less verbose by using a collection initializer:

```
LineList myLines = new LineList
{
    { "ABCD1", 1 },
    { "ABCD2", 1 },
    { "ABCD3", 1 }
};
```

And, of course, as the other answers state, it's trivial to extract the SKUs into a string array with LINQ:

```
string[] mySKUsArray = myLines.Select(myLine => myLine.Sku).ToArray();
```